# react native how to use multiple animations on a single element

Tags: react-native

i'm using the react-native-animatable plugin and i'd like to use multiple animations for the same text. Basically what i want to do is zoomIn a text with a duration of 1s and 0s delay and then when it's done perform a pulse animation on the same text using a duration of 1s and a delay of 3s. then finally zoomOut the same text with a duration of 1s and delay of 5s

so far only the last animation performs

here is my code

```
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#203546', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', }}>
    <Animatable.Text animation="zoomIn" duration={1000} delay={0} 
                     animation="pulse" duration={1000} delay={3000} 
                     animation="zoomOut" duration={1000} delay={5000} 
                    style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, position: 
                         'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>my text
   </Animatable.Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `ref` on the Text element and trigger the animation via the [Imperative Usage](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable#imperative-usage).

Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.textRef.zoomIn(1000).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.textRef.pulse(1000).then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.textRef.zoomOut(1000)
          }, 5000)
      }, 3000)
    })
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <Animatable.Text
        ref={el => this.textRef = el}
        style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}
      >
        my text
      </Animatable.Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment . I'd like to know how to set the delays between each animation from the answer above

Comment: @sam edited my answer. Easiest thing would be to add a `setTimeout`